# How to add price upon checking a check_box in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, stripe-payments, payola

I am working on a paid ad job board, and am using *#Payola-Payments (Implementation of **Stripe Payment Processor** with Rails Application)* to charge each job post on the app..

**This is what I like to do:**

> When a check_box is checked, I want the price the application will
>   deduct to change from default set price in my Jobs table, to the
>   addition of the check_box worth.

**Pictorial explanation of what I like to do:**

Upon checking the box, it's suppose to add $20 to my default price in jobs table.

> [image: My Job Post Form]

**schema.rb**

Note: A price default of $200 in cents (i.e. 20000) is set in my jobs table. The reason being what is required in Payola-payments documentation. So anytime anyone posts job advert, $200 will be deducted from his/her credit card by Stripe.

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20160827065822) do    
 create_table "jobs", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "title",            limit: 255
  t.string   "category",         limit: 255
  t.string   "location",         limit: 255
  t.text     "description"
  t.text     "to_apply"
  t.datetime "created_at",                                   null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at",                                   null: false
  t.string   "name",             limit: 255
  t.integer  "price",                        default: 20000
  t.string   "permalink",        limit: 255
  t.string   "stripeEmail",      limit: 255
  t.string   "payola_sale_guid", limit: 255
  t.string   "email",            limit: 255
  t.string   "website",          limit: 255
  t.string   "company_name",     limit: 255
  t.boolean  "highlighted"
 end
end
```

**What I have done to solve this:**

I defined a method inside my model (**job.rb**) called `price_modification` and called `before_save` on it, such that my model looks like this code below **but didn't work**:

```
class Job < ActiveRecord::Base

  include Payola::Sellable
  before_save :price_modification

  def price_modification
    price
  end

  def price_modification=(new_price)
    if :highlighted == t
      self.price += (price + 2000)
    else
      self.price = new_price
    end
  end

end
```

Thanks in advance.

Am using `Ruby 2.2.4` and `Rails 4.2.5.1`

Comment: Please explain "but it didn't work" and add some stack trace if necessary.

Comment: @RaVeN I meant it doesn't deduct $220. The default price which is $200 was deducted. The idea is just to change price Stripe will deduct if the check_box is checked when filling form for job post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`price_modification` is an accessor method that makes no changes.

The `before_save :price_modification` is calling the `price_modification` method which only returns the `price` value but makes no changes.

I'm not certain what you're looking for but my best guess is something like this:

```
class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...

  # Use before_create instead of before_save so
  # apply_extra_fees is *not* called multiple times.
  before_create :apply_extra_fees

  HIGHLIGHT_FEE_IN_CENTS = 2000

  def apply_extra_fees
    if highlighted?
      self.price += HIGHLIGHT_FEE_IN_CENTS
    end
  end

  ...
end
```

Comment: this is not the first time I will see you make a good answer to problems. Please help me. How do i get better and better in Ruby on Rails? I will really need that help.

Comment: Big question, many answers. Practice, write code, ask questions, explore, read, research, work alongside devs who will mentor you. Time - lots of time spent doing these things.